# classic asp syntax highliting inside javascript in Visual web developer ee 2008

Tags: asp-classic, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

How can visual web developer Express Edition highlight the classic asp-Tags (<% asp code %>) insight the Javascript code?

If i write
<script>
alert("<% =session("user_name %> ");
</script>

VWD highlights this as a string and not as asp-code. This is total confusing in these old files i'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue on Microsoft Connect with a few workarounds, however the syntax highlighting was removed in VS2008.  The response from Microsoft (verbatim):

> Thank you for this feedback. We are
>   depcrecting VB Script colorization and
>   intellisense support in Visual Studio
>   2008. We recommend to customers to use VS 2005 or VWD 2005 to edit VB
>   Script.
>   Those products can be installed on the
>   same machine as VS 2008 without any
>   issues.
>
> - Visual Web Developer Team

Check here for more information:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=290845